# NHibernate doesnt save object and also no error is showed

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, nhibernate

I have problem with saving object to database with NHibernate. Program throws no error but record is still not in database. I am also outputting sql queries and the query is not executed.

I use composite key in table "order_product". Table is child of "order".

Database table: **order_product**

```
order_id (PK)
product_id (PK)
count
price
```

Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
  <class name="Service.OrderProduct, Service" lazy="true" table="order_product">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="productId" column="product_id" type="string"/>
      <key-property name="orderId" column="order_id" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="count" type="int" column="count" not-null="true" />
    <property name="price" type="double" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Order"   column="order_id"   fetch="join" cascade="all"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

C# Object:

```
public class OrderProduct
{
    virtual public OrderProductPK orderProductPK { get; set; }
    virtual public int count { get; set; }
    virtual public string productId { get; set; }
    virtual public int orderId { get; set; }
    virtual public double price { get; set; }
    virtual public Order Order { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(Object o)
    {

        OrderProduct a = o as OrderProduct;
        if (a.productId.Equals(this.productId) && a.orderId==this.orderId)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 0;
        hashCode = hashCode ^ productId.GetHashCode() ^ orderId.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
public class OrderProductPK
{
    virtual public string productId { get; set; }
    virtual public int orderId { get; set; }

}
```

Save code:

```
OrderProduct op = new OrderProduct();
op.order_id= 133;
op.product_id = "product_key_id";
op.price = 20.4;
op.count = 10;
OpenSession().Save(op);
```

Comment: This looks like a many to many relation table.  If it is, is this table also mapped elsewhere, maybe implicitly in a HasMany?

Comment: It is true that "order_product" is many to many table but as it has some additional attributes (not only order_id & product_id) I use only many-to-one and one-to-many in my mapping.

Comment: I also tried to remove many-to-one mapping and save object but it still didn't work.

It seems like the problem is <composite-id> in my mapping. Is my OrderProduct class OK?

Comment: If you have log4net setup to log NHibernate, please post the portion of the log in debug level just before.save and and a .flush

Comment: 2010-08-29 09:16:31,647 [1] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener [(null)] <(null)> - saving transient instance
2010-08-29 09:16:31,653 [1] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener [(null)] <(null)> - generated identifier: component[productId,orderId]{'productId'='test_pid_1', 'orderId'='10'}, using strategy: NHibernate.Id.Assigned
2010-08-29 09:16:31,653 [1] DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener [(null)] <(null)> - saving [Service.OrderProduct#Service.OrderProduct]

Comment: I added surrogate key and now everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem  using surrogate key.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to either close (Dispose) the Session, or Flush it, to make NHibernate write the changes to the database.

Comment: I have tried with wrapping code in transaction and use transaction.Commit();
I also tried OpenSession().Flush();

But object is still not in database.

Comment: Saving other objects works OK (I tried saving other objects before and after code above).

Comment: OK, then it is probably not a flushing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the cascade all on the many-to-one, maybe even remove the fetch.

Comment: It doesn't work even if I delete <many-to-one> part of xml file. it seems I am having problem becouse of <composite-id> ...